# Creating dataframe from XML file with non-unique tags

Tags: python, pandas, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a directory of XML files, and I need to extract 4 values from each file and store to a dataframe/CSV.

The problem is some of the data I need to extract uses redundant tags (e.g., `<PathName>`) so I'm not sure of the best way to do this. I could specify the exact line # to extract, because it appears consistent with the files I have seen; but I am not certain that will always be the case, so doing it that way is too brittle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BxfMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2019/BXF BxfSchema.xsd" id="jffsdfs" dateTime="2023-02-02T20:11:38Z" messageType="Info" origin="url" originType="Delivery" userName="ABC Corp User" destination=" System" xmlns="http://sffe-ra.org/schema/1999/2023/BXF" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w9.org/4232/XMLSchema-instance">
  <BxfData action="Spotd">
    <Content timestamp="2023-02-02T20:11:38Z">
      <NonProgramContent>
        <Details>
          <SpotType>Paid</SpotType>
          <SpotType>Standard</SpotType>
          <Spotvertiser>
            <SpotvertiserName>Spot Plateau</SpotvertiserName>
          </Spotvertiser>
          <Agency>
            <AgencyName>Spot Plateau</AgencyName>
          </Agency>
          <Product>
            <Name></Name>
            <BrandName>zzTop</BrandName>
            <DirectResponse>
              <PhoneNo></PhoneNo>
              <PCode></PCode>
              <DR_URL></DR_URL>
            </DirectResponse>
          </Product>
        </Details>
        <ContentMetSpotata>
          <ContentId>
            <BHGXId idType="CISC" auth="Agency">AAAA1111999Z</BHGXId>
          </ContentId>
          <Name>Pill CC Dutch</Name>
          <Policy>
            <PlatformType>Spotcast</PlatformType>
          </Policy>
          <Media>
            <BaseBand>
              <Audio VO="true">
                <AnalogAudio primAudio="false" />
                <DigitalAudio>
                  <MPEGLayerIIAudio house="false" audioId="1" dualMono="false" />
                </DigitalAudio>
              </Audio>
              <Video withlate="false" sidebend="false">
                <Format>1182v</Format>
                <CCs>true</CCs>
              </Video>
              <AccessServices>
                <AudioDescription_DVS>false</AudioDescription_DVS>
              </AccessServices>
              <QC>Passed QC (AAAA1111103H )</QC>
            </BaseBand>
            <MediaLocation sourceType="Primary">
              <Location>
                <AssetServer PAA="true" FTA="true">
                  <PathName>zzTap_zzTop_AAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-bb.mp4</PathName>
                </AssetServer>
              </Location>
              <SOM>
                <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:00;00</SmpteTimeCode>
              </SOM>
              <Duration>
                <SmpteDuration>
                  <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:30;00</SmpteTimeCode>
                </SmpteDuration>
              </Duration>
            </MediaLocation>
            <MediaLocation sourceType="Proxy" qualifer="Low-res">
              <Location>
                <AssetServer PAA="true" FTA="true">
                  <PathName>https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52f</PathName>
                </AssetServer>
              </Location>
              <SOM>
                <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:00;00</SmpteTimeCode>
              </SOM>
              <Duration>
                <SmpteDuration>
                  <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:30;00</SmpteTimeCode>
                </SmpteDuration>
              </Duration>
            </MediaLocation>
            <MediaLocation sourceType="Preview" qualifer="Thumbnail">
              <Location>
                <AssetServer PAA="true" FTA="true">
                  <PathName>https://f9-int-5.rainxyz.com/url.com/media/t43fs/423gs-389a-40a4.jpg?inline</PathName>
                </AssetServer>
              </Location>
              <SOM>
                <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:00;00</SmpteTimeCode>
              </SOM>
              <Duration>
                <SmpteDuration>
                  <SmpteTimeCode>00:00:00;00</SmpteTimeCode>
                </SmpteDuration>
              </Duration>
            </MediaLocation>
          </Media>
        </ContentMetSpotata>
      </NonProgramContent>
    </Content>
  </BxfData>
</BxfMessage>
```

Is there a more flexible method so that I can get consistent output like:

```
FileName                                Brand   ID              URL
zzTap_zzTop_AAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-bb zzTop   AAAA1111999Z    https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52f
zzTap_zzTab_BAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-cc zzTab   BAAA1111999Z    https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52c
zzTap_zzTan_CAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-dd zzTan   CAAA1111999Z    https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew523
zzTap_zzTon_DAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-zz zzTon   DAAA1111999Z    https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52y
```

Comment: how do u know when it's the correct <path name> when opening the file manually? if it's by the parent tag, iterate to it first, if it's by the form of the content validate it, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse one XML file using `beautifulsoup` you can use this example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_info(xml_file):
    with open(xml_file, 'r') as f_in:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'xml')

    file_name = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'PathName' and '.mp4' in tag.text).text.rsplit('.mp4', maxsplit=1)[0]
    url = soup.select_one('[sourceType="Proxy"] PathName').text
    brand_name = soup.select_one('BrandName').text
    id_ = soup.select_one('BHGXId').text

    return file_name, brand_name, id_, url

print(get_info('your_file.xml'))
```

Prints:

```
('zzTap_zzTop_AAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-bb', 'zzTop', 'AAAA1111999Z', 'https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52f')
```

Answer (score 0):

How looks your code? Here is my try.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("zzTab.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

ns = "{http://sffe-ra.org/schema/1999/2023/BXF}"
list_of_interest = [f"{ns}PathName", f"{ns}BHGXId", f"{ns}BrandName"]

PathName_dir_list = []
PathName_file_list = []
BHGXId_list = []
BrandName_list = []

for elem in root.iter():
    #print(elem.tag, elem.text)
    if elem.tag in list_of_interest:
        if elem.tag == f"{ns}PathName" and '.mp4' not in elem.text:
            #print("Dir:",elem.text)
            PathName_dir_list.append(elem.text)
        if elem.tag == f"{ns}PathName" and '.mp4' in elem.text:
            #print("File:",elem.text)
            PathName_file_list.append(elem.text)          
        if elem.tag == f"{ns}BHGXId":
            #print("ID", elem.text)
            BHGXId_list.append(elem.text)
        if elem.tag == f"{ns}BrandName":
            print("Brand", elem.text)
            BrandName_list.append(elem.text)

t = zip(PathName_dir_list, PathName_file_list,  BHGXId_list, BrandName_list,)
list_of_tuples = list(t)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns = ['Path', 'File', 'ID', 'Brand'])
df.to_csv('file_list.csv')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If working with `BeautifulSoup`, I suggest looking into using [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) so that you can do something like

```py
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getXMLdata(xmlFile:str, defaultVal=None):
    with open(xmlFile, 'r') as f: xSoup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
    selRef = {
        'FileName': 'MediaLocation[sourceType="Primary"] Location',
        'Brand': 'BrandName', 'ID': 'ContentId',
        'URL': 'MediaLocation[sourceType="Proxy"] Location'
    }
    xfDets = {} # {'fromFile': xmlFile} 
    for k, sel in selRef.items():
        t = xSoup.select_one(sel)
        xfDets[k] = t.get_text(' ').strip() if t else defaultVal 

    fn = xfDets.get('FileName')
    if isinstance(fn, str) and '.' in fn:  # remove extensions like ".mp4"
        xfDets['FileName'] = '.'.join(fn.split('.')[:-1])
    return xfDets
```

---

Since I've seen only one example, I can't know for sure if the selectors in `selRef` will apply for *all* your files; but I saved the snippet from your question to a file name `x.xml`, and **`getXMLdata('x.xml')`** returned

```py
{'FileName': 'zzTap_zzTop_AAAA1111999Z_30s_Pill_aa-bb',
 'Brand': 'zzTop',
 'ID': 'AAAA1111999Z',
 'URL': 'https://app.url.com/DMM/DL/wew52f'}
```

---

If you had a list of paths to XML files (let's say `filesList`), you could tabulate their outputs with pandas like

```py
# import pandas
# filesList = ['x.xml', ...] ## LIST OF XML FILES
xDF = pandas.DataFrame([getXMLdata(x) for x in filesList])
```

[image: opdf]

**<sup>[ If you wanted to save that output to a csv file, you can use [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) like *`xDF.to_csv('xmldata.csv')`*. ]</sup>**